# How to Get mac address in Universal Apps?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone

I need to get the MAC address in a Universal Windows Application.
   I searched for an equivalent code but I did not succeed.
   Could someone guide me how to do this?

Ricardo Souza.

Comment: This code worked for me on a UWP app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097870/c-sharp-get-mac-address-in-universal-apps/34098615

Answer (score 2):

> How to Get mac address in Universal Apps?

AFAIK, currently there is no API can get the local machine MAC address directly in UWP app. In Win32 application we use [`NetworkInterface.GetPhysicalAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getphysicaladdress(v=vs.110).aspx) method which is currently not implemented in UWP. But it seems like it is plan to support UWP, details please reference [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9675).

So, temporary for a workaround you may try to use the [`GetAdaptersAddresses`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx) method of `PInvoke` as @ChristophvanderFecht mentioned. For a  sample about `GetAdaptersAddress` you may reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672520/how-to-get-unicast-dns-and-gateway-address-in-uwp).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,

      I am new to using C #.

      I checked the two guidelines, which is how I am programming in C # the first example: GetAdapterAddress at "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx" , It is in C ++ and I can not use it.

      Already the second example I could not understand how to fetch the MAC address.

      So I still do not know how to get MAC address for Universal Windows applications - Windows and Windows Phone.

Thank you so much

Comment: @RicardoSouza, the sample I linked is a completed sample, just copy the code snippet and run it locally. If you still cannot , please detail what you cannot understand.  Additionally,  please add @ for someone or someone will not see your comment.